# Why do graph algorithms reference the previous edge?

Tags: algorithm, graph

Almost all path-related graph algorithms seem to use a pattern that involves saving the edge that was used to get to the current vertex. In contrast, why doesn't the current vertex hold any reference to the next edge, similar to linked lists? I'm guessing you could, but what are the tradeoffs?

Comment: What if there are multiple next edges?  Which one will you store?  It sounds path dependent to me.  "How did I get here?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, there are several mixed concepts here. First, I'll go through the Graph data structure.

## Graph representation

A data structure is a way to structure data (ok, this one was easy). This is how your graph will be represented internally. And there are plenty of possibilities.

If you think about it a little bit, there are two central concepts in a graph: edges and vertices. How you choose to store them is completely up to you. For easier explanation, I'll consider vertices are given a unique number from 0 to V-1.

There are several representations around, and depending of your problem one may be more appropriate than another. Basically, there is redundant information between vertices and edges, so creating a structure for both is overkill. I'll go through both cases now.

You can create explicit an explicit Vertex structure. Each Vertex contains a list of Vertices it can go too. The Graph structure should maintain an array of all the Vertices in order to make it efficient. This is the structure you're referring, and it's a valid one.

In this case, the edges are implicit: if a Vertex can go to another, then there is an edge between the two. However, no Edge structure is created, it is implied by the list contained in each vertex.

Second possibility, create an Edge structure. Each Edge contains its starting point, and end point (which are vertices, and can be represented as integers). The Graph data structure holds an array, and for each slot, stores a list of all edges starting (or ending) at this vertex.

Again, this is a valid data structure, usually called the adjacency-list representation. And this time, there is no explicit Vertex structure: they are integers contained into Edges.

Using explicit Edges (and implicit Vertices), there is also the adjacency-matrix representation which can be handy if the graph is dense.

In the end, choosing the representation of a Graph is about which is the best suited in your case, and which you understand better, but there is no absolute rule.

In my case, I understood the adjacency-list quickly, but had a hard time getting my head around the first representation, so you should pick the one you are more comfortable with.

## Graph algorithm

Now come algorithms. The idea is, given a Graph structure (no matter which representation is behind), which provides some defined functions, process this Graph to get some informations about it.

In the case of DFS/BFS, the informations searched is to traverse the graph from one source vertex to every attainable vertex. It's true that regarding those algorithms, each vertex is associated to one of his predecessors.

That is because the information we want from these algorithms is to get **one** of the path from the source to another vertex. Of course there are other paths, but this does not matter.

In fact, finding all the possible paths from one vertex to every other is an NP-complete problem, and sometimes impossible (if there is a cycle for example).

That's why only the predecessor of a vertex is stored: because all we want is **one** path among others, and it makes those algorithms efficient, both in terms of space and memory.

I hope this answers your question and cleared your thoughts.

Comment: I was more curious about the *design*. But I took a closer look at dijkstra's algorithm, and only referencing the previous edge led to an elegant way of dealing with "disconnecting" a previous path, as it's simply a side effect of changing the previous edge.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what examples you are referring to, but usually in a directed graph a vertex *does* hold a reference to "next edges", IE vertices in the neighborhood of a node.  That it is usually more useful than holding vertices whose neighborhoods contain the current node.  You could record both, but the downside is that:

1. You double the disk space to store the graph
2. You double (on average) the time to remove/add an edge.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about 2 different concepts in this question; algorithm and data structure. The point in path-related algorithms( say BFS DFS) is that you should be able to traverse the paths, that is the algorithm, but how you want to design your data structure is up to you and depends what exactly problem you want to solve, what are your limitations and exact requirements. You can check Half-Edge data structure, Face-Based Data Structures that are used to solve complex topological and algorithmic problems with graphs (to be exact meshes).
Hope it helps